# What happens to your legacy when you transfer characters in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

My server is just ridiculous sometimes. So I have looked intensively into another server and things are quite better there. So I have 2 higher level characters (55, 30+) on this server. What happens to my legacy if I transfer only one of them and the other one later?

Will my legacy stay on the original server? What will happen there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have everything from your Legacy on the new server (unlocks, level, etc.) and the old should be unaffected.

It will combine things if you have different Legacies (i.e., a character already on the new server) with different unlocks so you get the best of both worlds, including the higher Legacy level.

For slightly more detail see [Dulfy on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/1fnxpq/paid_character_transfer_details/).