# SWTOR Character Transfer & Legacy Level

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have level 35 legacy in my main character's server. And I created another one to play with my friends in another server which has level 20 legacy.

Now my friends quit the game, and I want to transfer the little one to my main's server.

I checked the link below:

[What happens to your legacy when you transfer characters in SWTOR?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159431/what-happens-to-your-legacy-when-you-transfer-characters-in-swtor/159434#159434)

Here it says:

- Unlocks will pass, quite nice.
- Old one will remain and won't be affected, nice as well

But what about Legacy level? I have 35 here, if I transfer the small one to my server which is 20, will my legacy level still be 35, or will they merge the xp and become a higher legacy level?

Comment: AFAIK you'll keep the legacy level 35 and it will not get merged. *NOTE* I'm not entirely sure about this.

Comment: I'm sorry was unclear.  You keep the Legacy level on the original server, and you apt it on the new server IF it is higher than the existing.  In other words, the same as everything else.  I will update my answer there and VTC this question.

Comment: Well, it wasn't a duplicate till you edited your answer there ^^ no worries, got my answer thank you.